# Table of unequal sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, table

from the following table we have,

```
Table[i,{i,0,4,1}]
```

we `(0,1,2,3,4)`

can we have somehow

```
(0,2,3,4)
```

?
a formula `Table[i-....,{i,....,...}]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove specific entries, there are at least 10 ways to do it. One way could be to insert an `If` inside the table. Something like

```
Table[If[i == 1, Nothing, i], {i, 0, 4, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want more general approach, need to give a more general problem. Otherwise, this is very specific problem. You could simply also remove the `1` from the output afterwords?

Help on `Nothing` says

> Nothing represents an element of a list that will automatically be 
> removed.

Answer (score 6):

With the list

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 10, 1};
```

you can combine [**`FirstPosition`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html?v=13.2) and [**`Delete`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html?v=13.2)

```
Delete[list, FirstPosition[list, _?(# == 2 &)]]
```

in order to remove only the first time `2` appears

> [image: l1]

If you use [**`DeleteCases`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html?v=13.2) with [**`Infinity`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity.html?v=13.2) as level specification

```
DeleteCases[list, 2, Infinity]
```

you'll remove all instances of `2`

> [image: l2]

Answer (score 5):

Using position with `Delete`:

```
Delete[Table[i, {i, 0, 4, 1}], {2}]
(*{0, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Using element with `DeleteElements`:

```
DeleteElements[Table[i, {i, 0, 4, 1}], {1}]
(*{0, 2, 3, 4}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

A  [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) method:

```
Reap[{Do[If[i==1,Continue[]];Sow[i], {i,0,4}]}][[2,1]]

(* {0, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

And (for example):

```
Reap[{Do[If[i==1 || i == 5,Continue[]];Sow[i], {i,0,10}]}][[2,1]]

(* {0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Comment: With **Scan**: `Reap[Scan[If[#==1,Nothing,Sow[#]]&]@Range[0,4]][[2,1]]`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 10, 1};
```

To delete all 2s

```
ReplaceAt[list, 2 :> Nothing, All]
```

{0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 1}

or, like E. Chan-López showed

```
DeleteElements[list, {2}]
```

{0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 1}

To delete only the first 2

```
DeleteElements[list, 1 -> {2}]
```

{0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 9, 2, 10, 1}

To delete the first two 2s:

```
DeleteElements[list, 2 -> {2}]
```

{0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 10, 1}

or

```
SubsetReplace[list, {Repeated[2, {2}]} -> Nothing]
```

{0, 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 10, 1}